# NoClassDefFoundError with spark

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, sbt

I'm trying to run an extremely trivial spark context instance using IntelliJ. However, I'm running into an issue where I'm receiving a `NoClassDefFoundError`:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Product$class
    at org.apache.spark.SparkConf$DeprecatedConfig.<init>(SparkConf.scala:609)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkConf$.<init>(SparkConf.scala:473)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkConf$.<clinit>(SparkConf.scala)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkConf.set(SparkConf.scala:71)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkConf.setAppName(SparkConf.scala:86)
    at test$.main(test.scala:8)
    at test.main(test.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Product$class
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 12 more
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
17/01/27 00:24:37 INFO Utils: Shutdown hook called
```

I've tried shifting everything from my Sbt versions to Scala versions. Here are my configurations:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I'm trying to run this code:

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}

object test {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val conf = new SparkConf()
    conf.setAppName("test")
    conf.setMaster("local[2]")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    println(sc)
  }
}
```

Is there anything that I don't know about Scala and Spark version incompatibilities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explicitly add the Scala library and xml dependencies

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-xml</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.0-M4</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: which xml file do I add it to?

Comment: I'm a maven guy, if you are using maven add it in pom.xml. Otherwise, make sure you have scala-library.jar and scala-xml.jar in your classpath whichever build system you are using.